# How to update tablesorter onclick in dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm trying to use tablesorter on a dynamic HTML table. When the data in the table changes, and I try to sort, the table messes up; it adds the previous data and the current data and combines them both into one table, and it is also sorting other tables!! How can I make it so when the table changes, tablesorter will update? I'm populating the table from a .csv using jQuery, and the table is dynamic, because the HTML page the table is in has multiple file names, if you click on one, the data from that file will be loaded to that table

I'm using multiple tables, and one tablesorter, but here's one of my tables:

```
<div id="origtable">
    <table border="1" id="table_side">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Origin <br> Country</th>

              <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Here's my **tablesorter:**

```
/* tried this at first because I'm waiting for data from .csv file to populate table
setInterval(function(){sortStuff()},1000);
    function sortStuff(){
        $("table").tablesorter({ 
        sortList: [[1,1]]
        });
        $("table").trigger("update");
    }
*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        sortList: [[0,1]]
        });
    });

    $("table").on( "click", function() {
    $("table").trigger("update");
});
```

EDIT 1:
jquery function used to populate html table after reading from .csv (this jquery code is in a seperate .js file)

```
function populateTableCounts(rowkey, tablename, hashdata)
    {
        var rowhtml = "";
        $.each(hashdata, function (key, value) {
             key = key.replace(/-/g, ' / ');
             key = key.replace(/:/g, ' , ');

             var rowdata=countrow.replace('$row_key', key);
             rowdata=rowdata.replace('$row_val', value);

            //add row <tr> to var rowhtml   
            rowhtml += rowdata;          
        });

        //append populated rowhtml to TBODY
        $('#' + tablename + ' tbody').append(rowhtml);
    }
```

Comment: I dont know how tablesorter works but i think that you need to call $("table").tablesorter({ 
                    sortList: [[0,1]]
                    });
                }); again instead of $("table").trigger("update");

Comment: @HaSuKrOnOs That didn't solve it, when the table dynamically changes, it adds rows from previous table.

Comment: Yeah, ignore that, check my answer i think the problem is cause you are not doing this con document load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my comment is trigger("update") the function you need, but check if this code works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("table").tablesorter({ 
           sortList: [[0,1]]
     });

     $("table").click(function(){ $("table").trigger("update"); });
});
```

### EDIT

If you are using get to obtain csv data you need something like this:

```
$.get("your/csv/file.csv",function(csv){
   //... code that handle your csv and put into table
   //...

   //AT END UPDATE TABLE
   $("table").trigger("update");
});
```

### EDIT2

```
function populateTableCounts(rowkey, tablename, hashdata)
{
    var rowhtml = "";
    $.each(hashdata, function (key, value) {
         key = key.replace(/-/g, ' / ');
         key = key.replace(/:/g, ' , ');

         var rowdata=countrow.replace('$row_key', key);
         rowdata=rowdata.replace('$row_val', value);

        //add row <tr> to var rowhtml   
        rowhtml += rowdata;          
    });

    //append populated rowhtml to TBODY
    $('#' + tablename + ' tbody').append(rowhtml);

    //You can do this
    $('#' + tablename).trigger("update");

    //or this if you want $('table').trigger('update');
}
```

You can do this things without problem, you need to take care that the elements must be loaded so execute all on $(document).ready.

There is no problem if the js script is on another file.

Comment: This doens't add previous rows, but one problem is that loads the page with the wrong column sorted (it should sort column two by descending order because "sortList:[[0,1]]") and the other problem is that when i click on a column header on one table, it sorts a few other tables too.

Comment: OK, so you need to do $("table").trigger("update") when the data is loaded, how you are laoding the data?

Comment: From a .csv file using jquery

Comment: I saw your edit, I can see my problem now but I can't use that code exactly, so can you show me some code to wait like half a second (until table is populated from .csv) before I use the table sorter?

Comment: You can use setTimeout, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp but show me your code im sure that we can find a better solution

Comment: Check my answer, there is no problem executen even if is on another file.

Comment: Works great on FF28, but page loads extremely slow on IE8. I think I'm gonna go with the setTimeout solution since it's much faster. Thanks!